# Paperclip can't access to upload file

Tags: paperclip

I have the following model :

```
has_paper_trail                              # Track model with paper_trail
has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>"}, 
  :path => ":rails_root/public/attachments/:project_id/ressources/:id_:basename_:style.:extension",
  :url  => ":rails_root/public/attachments/:project_id/ressources/:id_:basename_:style.:extension"

belongs_to :project

# convert :project_id in path to project_:project_id
Paperclip.interpolates :project_id do |attachment, style|
  "project_#{attachment.instance.project_id}"
end
```

It works but when I want to display image in my view it doesn't find the image, how can I fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by replace

```
:url  => ":rails_root/public/attachments/:project_id/ressources/:id_:basename_:style.:extension"
```

By

```
:url  => "/attachments/:project_id/ressources/:id_:basename_:style.:extension"
```